# AppDomain is marked for unload due to memory pressure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

On a 32-bit SQL 2005 Enterprise box, I keep getting "AppDomain XX (DB_NAME.dbo[runtime].YY) is marked for unload due to memory pressure".

- I have 8GB physical RAM
- AWE is set up to use 4.5GB
- No -g512 startup parameter set
- This instance of SQL is listening on 3 different ports

Among other things I have noticed:

- Little to almost no paging at all
- CPU hovers around 20-30% which is consistent to norms
- MEMORYCLERK_SQLCONNECTIONPOOL is around 10616
- I get "AppDomain XX (DB_NAME.dbo[runtime].YY) created", "AppDomain XX (DB_NAME.dbo[runtime].YY) is marked for unload due to memory pressure."AppDomain XX (DB_NAME.dbo[runtime].YY) unloaded." all in the same minute and this repeats every 5 minutes or so.

The DB above only has only one Assembly and it has been running fine for many months.
The problem only started recently and the only changes I could think of is an application server increasing its number of connection in its pool from 200-300 to about 1000.

Can anybody help me shed a light on this issue?

Comment: You could try looking at some relevant memory-related statistics in, say, Process Explorer: In addition to the global Commit and Physical Memory graphs, it would probably be a good idea to look at the per-process page fault counts, especially page fault delta (since that is an indication of how much memory pressure a process is causing).

Comment: Are you pointing towards an external pressure rather from SQL itself? If there is external pressure, shouldn't I see some form of paging?

Comment: Well, I guess so ... I've never really heard of memory pressure that doesn't involve paging. Where are you getting your numbers? (Does SQL server do its own "paging"?)

Comment: I am looking at the OS physical memory. In Task Manager the Physical Available Memory is around 2.5GB as a matter of fact.

Comment: The AWE is only used for the buffer pool, not for .NET. It is a normal 32bit process running embedded, thus it itself can only use 2gig and remember this is ADDRESS space, not actual memory use. You really should use 64bit OS and 64bit SQL server with more than 2gig mem in the system.

Comment: You might want to look here for more detailed info on how SQL Server uses memory: http://mssqlwiki.com/sqlwiki/sql-performance/basics-of-sql-server-memory-architecture/

Answer (score 0):

With 32 bit os and DB you are hitting a limit of 4gb ram. AWE just enabled restricting memory for SQL server so that its is not released to other process.

You should plan to upgrade to 64 bit version to optimally use the memory.

Some more pointers to similar question are here.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63720/app-domain-is-marked-for-unload-due-to-memory-pressure